# How can I change day's time interval on oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a this query and working correctly.

```
select TO_CHAR(A.CREATE_DATE, 'DD') DAYs,TO_CHAR(A.CREATE_DATE, 'MM') MONTHS,
SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.RCPT_DTIME,'HH24') = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TIME8,
SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(A.RCPT_DTIME,'HH24') = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TIME7
                              
                              from PERSON A, HRM B
                              where  A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID                            
                              AND A.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE(:i_CREATE_DATE || '00','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
                              AND A.CREATE_DATE < TO_DATE(:i_CREATE_DATE || '00','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')                                 
                              GROUP BY TO_CHAR(A.CREATE_DATE, 'DD'),TO_CHAR(A.RCPT_DTIME, 'MM')
                              ORDER BY MONTHS,DAYs
```

Normal query's time get start from 00:00 to day after day's 00:00.
But I want to make day's time range as day's 07:00am and tomorrow's 07:00am. How can I make this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `TRUNC` the date and then add 7 hours. As example this will select today 7am and tomorrow 7am:

```
SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) + INTERVAL '7' HOUR, 
TRUNC(sysdate) + 1 + INTERVAL '7' HOUR FROM dual;
```

So you can use this within a where clause, something like

```
SELECT columnselection FROM tableselection 
WHERE ...AND TRUNC(yourdate) + INTERVAL '7' HOUR <= datetocompare 
AND TRUNC(yourdate) + 1 + INTERVAL '7' HOUR >= datetocompare AND...
```

You could also use `BETWEEN` when comparing dates instead of <= and >=, some people think this is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the solution? anyway how can I add minute interval?

Comment: Of course, you can. As example TRUNC(sysdate) + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE -> will be today at 00:30. You can also combine both, as example TRUNC(sysdate) + 1 + INTERVAL '7' HOUR + INTERVAL '15' MINUTE -> will be tomorrow at 07:15. Please mark this answer as accepted if it's a sufficient help for you.